# Unexpected token '.' from poppinss, after running node ace migration:run

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I'm trying to run `node ace migration:run`, but it won't execute due to this error.

I've tried reinstalling packages with yarn and npm, as well as rebooting computer.

I don't have a single clue on how to fix it or how to Google for a solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a syntax error, and it points at [`?.` (the optional chaining operator)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

You're using a version of Node.js that doesn't support the `?.` operator (versions older than Node 14).

Upgrade your Node.js to 14.0 or newer.

Comment: I'm using node 12. it must be that!